# Can I package a third party application installer along with my electron application?

Tags: python, reactjs, electron, powerbi-desktop, electron-builder

I'm currently working on a project which has a **react** frontend and **python** backend and some functions involving **Power Bi desktop**. As I'm trying to package the react and python in an **electron application** with the help of **electron builder**, can I include the installer of Power Bi desktop so that when the user installs my application, they can also install the Power Bi desktop?

I'm expecting that during the installation process of my application, the installer of Power Bi desktop should run and the user should be able to install it together with my application.